# Is it possible to calculate the probability that two samples are drawn from the same distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, anderson-darling-test

Given $X_1$..$X_n$ and $Y_1$..$Y_n$ drawn from unknown distributions $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ respectively, statistical tests such as two-sample Kolomogorov-Smirnov, Cramer-von Mises, and Anderson-Darling tests have been devised to test the null hypothesis $\mathcal{H}: F(x) = G(x)$ using various test statistics.

But rather than hypothesis testing, I am more interested in quantifying the probability, $\mathcal{P}(X_1..Xn,Y_1..Y_n | F(x) = G(x))$ without knowing $F(x)$ or $G(x)$. Is this possible?

The above tests give $\mathcal{P}(Z\ge{}z | F(x) = G(x))$ where $Z$ is the test statistic, but this is not what I want.

I tried to find how the two-sample Kolomogorov test statistic was derived, but nothing useful came up... All the papers I have found either simply state the proposed test statistic or study its distribution under the null hypothesis.

Given order statistics $X_{(1)}$..$X_{(n)}$ and $Y_{(1)}$..$Y_{(n)}$, is there anything useful we can say about $X_{(i)} - Y_{(i)}$ irrespective of the distributions $F(x)$ and $G(x)$?

Comment: On the question: "*Is it possible to calculate the probability that two samples are drawn from the same distribution?*" -- the short answer is 'no'. How would you distinguish between $F=G$ and something *very* close to equality but still unequal? The longer answer is "maybe you kind of can do that, if you're a Bayesian".

Comment: @Glen_b I don't mind Bayesian methods... any hints?

Comment: Conventionally, you need to have a prior, and some kind of likelihood to obtain a posterior. This is somewhat difficult if you can't specify F and G, but there may be some kind of nonparametric approach possible here (some kind of mixture modelling perhaps?). You might then be comparing a model where all the components were the same to one where there were one or more components in the mixture that were not the same for both. You *still* don't avoid the problem that you really can't tell F=G from F and G being very very close but different, and I can't think of a good way of avoiding that.

Comment: My question specifically asks about P(X1..Xn,Y1..Yn|F(x)=G(x)). If I understand Bayes' Rule correctly, this is the likelihood. So how can I calculate this? I want to calculate a probability, since I can't know for sure whether F = G. I'd like to quantify the uncertainty in my belief that F = G given the observed samples.

Comment: You might like to take a look at the definition of likelihood.

Comment: You're right. Likelihood is defined based on a set of parameters, not a hypothesis. But more concretely, how would you derive this likelihood you refer to? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're outside my area of expertise, but the nonparametric approach I was suggesting was that you could set up some kind of mixture model for F and G. I can't *tell* you what kind of mixture exactly (and without that, you don't get a likelihood), because that would require me to make assumptions you won't make explicit; I sure as heck can't make them explicit *for* you.

Comment: You are trying to transform a matter of _distance_ between two distributions, $d(F,G)$ into an _event_, $\{F=G\}$, and then assign some probability to it, conditional on some observed data. If you partition the event space into $\{F=G\}$ and $\{F\neq G\}$, even conditional on some data, do you think that the event $\{F=G\}$ can be assigned any other probability except zero?

Comment: Note that the question in the second paragraph is quite different from the question in the title.