# Justifying data samples are from different distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, p-value

Let $x \in \{0,1\}^N$, and

\begin{align}
    D &= \begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           x_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           x_{M}
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

So that $D \in \{0,1\}^{N \times M} $.

This is the original dataset. The zero indicate a trait and 1 indicate absence of the trait. The order of sequence of the  0's and 1's matter for each $x$.
A new data sample $D'$ was generated using a different generation process (for example Boltzman machine).

I am looking for a test statistic to show  that $D$ and $D'$ are different distributions or otherwise. For example, it would be possible to use Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, but I am not certain this would be appropriate for the data. Another contending approach is kernel 2 sample test. Again, while this might work I am wondering if there is any caveat.

Or is there any other statistical test that might be more relevant?

References:

[Test for difference between 2 empirical discrete distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88764/test-for-difference-between-2-empirical-discrete-distributions)

[Method to justify claim that two samples come from the same distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204359/method-to-justify-claim-that-two-samples-come-from-the-same-distribution)

[Is Kolmogorov-Smirnov test valid with discrete distributions?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/is-kolmogorov-smirnov-test-valid-with-discrete-distributions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hypothesis to test is:

$H_0$: $D$ and $D'$ are random draws from the same population.

$H_1$: The population from which $D$ was drawn is not the same population from which $D'$ was drawn.

### A possible approach

Here I modify the notation so that $D \in \{0,1\}^{n \times k}$ and $D' \in \{0,1\}^{m \times k}$.

Combine $D$ and $D'$, then partition the observations in $k$ different ways, each corresponding to the presence of the $i^{\text{th}}$ trait, with $i\in\{1...k\}$. Given $H_0$, the number of observations from $D'$ in the partition with the $i^{\text{th}}$ trait should follow the hypergeometric distribution with PMF:

$$p(a'_i|m,n,a_i)=\frac{\binom{m}{a'_i}\binom{n}{a_i}}{\binom{m+n}{a_i+a'_i}}$$
where $a_i$ and $a'_i$ are the total number of observations in $D$ and $D'$ with the $i^{\text{th}}$ trait.

Further, if $S_i=U(F(a'_i-1;m,n,a_i),F(a'_i;m,n,a_i))$, then $S_i\sim{U(0,1)}$, again assuming $H_0$. Test for $H_0$ by testing if $S\sim{U(0,1)}$, using, e.g., Kolmogorov-Smirnov (which may require relaxing the requirement of independence between the $S_i$).

Demonstrating in R:

```
set.seed(704776517)
n <- 100L
m <- 40L
k <- 9L

# simulate 1000 KS p-values for identically distributed observations
p <- replicate(
  1e3,
  {
    x <- mapply(\(p) rbinom(n, 1, p), seq(0.1, 0.9, length.out = k))
    y <- mapply(\(p) rbinom(m, 1, p), seq(0.1, 0.9, length.out = k))
    csy <- colSums(y)
    csxy <- colSums(x) + csy
    S <- sapply(1:k, \(i) runif(1, phyper(csy[i] - 1, m, n, csxy[i]), phyper(csy[i], m, n, csxy[i])))
    ks.test(S, punif)$p.value
  }
)

plot(ecdf(p), col = "blue")
lines(0:1, 0:1)
```

[image]

```
# simulate p-values when the distributions are slightly different
p <- replicate(
  1e3,
  {
    x <- mapply(\(p) rbinom(n, 1, p), seq(0.1, 0.9, length.out = k))
    y <- mapply(\(p) rbinom(m, 1, p), seq(0.2, 0.8, length.out = k))
    csy <- colSums(y)
    csxy <- colSums(x) + csy
    S <- sapply(1:k, \(i) runif(1, phyper(csy[i] - 1, m, n, csxy[i]), phyper(csy[i], m, n, csxy[i])))
    ks.test(S, punif)$p.value
  }
)

plot(ecdf(p), col = "blue")
lines(0:1, 0:1)
```

[image]

```
# simulate p-values when the distributions are even more different
p <- replicate(
  1e3,
  {
    x <- mapply(\(p) rbinom(n, 1, p), seq(0.1, 0.9, length.out = k))
    y <- mapply(\(p) rbinom(m, 1, p), seq(0.3, 0.7, length.out = k))
    csy <- colSums(y)
    csxy <- colSums(x) + csy
    S <- sapply(1:k, \(i) runif(1, phyper(csy[i] - 1, m, n, csxy[i]), phyper(csy[i], m, n, csxy[i])))
    ks.test(S, punif)$p.value
  }
)

plot(ecdf(p), col = "blue")
lines(0:1, 0:1)
```

[image]

The final demonstration is in log-space, so as to test if $S\sim\text{exp}(1)$. (This formulation is not actually needed here, but it demonstrates how to maintain numeric stability if the proportion of observations of $D$ or $D'$ in the partition is very unbalanced).

```
# simulate p-values when the distributions are very different
p <- replicate(
  1e4,
  {
    x <- mapply(\(p) rbinom(n, 1, p), seq(0.1, 0.9, length.out = k))
    y <- mapply(\(p) rbinom(m, 1, p), seq(0.7, 0.3, length.out = k))
    csy <- colSums(y)
    csxy <- colSums(x) + csy
    S <- sapply(1:k, \(i) (a <- -phyper(csy[i], m, n, csxy[i], log.p = TRUE)) - log1p(runif(1)*expm1(phyper(csy[i] - 1, m, n, csxy[i], log.p = TRUE) + a)))
    ks.test(S, pexp)$p.value
  }
)

plot(ecdf(p), col = "blue")
lines(0:1, 0:1)
```

[image]